# c++ operator string and char* causing ambiguous error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a class with conversion operators to string and char*, this makes ambiguous call error when trying to create a string.
assume i have the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
A(){};
operator const char*() const { return "a" };
operator const string() const { return "b" };
}
```

and the following main programs:

```
int main()
{
A a;
string b = string(a);
return 0;
}
```

this causing ambiguous call error to basic_string(A&)
also tried the following:

```
class A
{
public:
A(){};
operator const char*() const { return "a" };
explicit operator const string() const { return "b" };
}

int main()
{
A a;
string b = static_cast<string>(a);
return 0;
}
```

this causing the same error. I need to have both operators in my code, how can i 
make this work?

note: using string b = a works but I need the string(a) format to work aswell

note 2: not using explicit keywork makes operator= ambiguous

Comment: @Sergey I can't spot a local variable there?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518145/c-overloading-conversion-operator-for-custom-type-to-stdstring).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah, yes, it should be compiled to the data segment.

Comment: @Sergey: It's not a local variable, it is a string literal.  [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) in 2.3.5 p16 says "Evaluating a *string-literal* results in a string literal object with **static** storage duration" (my emphasis).

Comment: Unrelated, but having the operator return `const string` is a pessimisation, because it prevents moving from the returned value. You should change it to just conver to `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make them both `explicit` and use `static_cast`:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    explicit operator const char*() const { return "a"; };
    explicit operator const string() const { return "b"; };
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    string b = static_cast<string>(a); // works, b now has "b" as value
    const char * c = static_cast< const char *>(a); // works too, c now has "a" as value
    return 0;
}
```